# Finding value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin(\sin(\sin(.......(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right))))$

Tags: limits

Finding  value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sin(\sin(\sin(.......(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right))))$

Attempt: $\displaystyle \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$

so $\displaystyle \sin(\sin \frac{\pi}{2})= \sin(1)$

could  some help me how to  solve it,thanks

Comment: The limit is not a function of $n$. Is $n$ the number of times that sin() is applied?